# Create `Pediatrics` tag burn `Children`?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, tags

Seems like we could have children/kids/babies refer to Pediatrics in general (we don't seem to have a lot on neonates, but that's another consideration).

As a medical site it seems more appropriate to have pediatrics, then again I work in PED:ID so I could be biased.

Comment: Cross-ref: http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/466/where-do-health-related-parenting-questions-go

Comment: how about make the *Children* tag as a synonym of the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree completely. It's done.

If you want to edit the tag, please feel free to do so.