# Where do health-related parenting questions go?

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it seems that diseases and injuries and treatments of those are on topic, regardless of age.  Also on topic are Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health" and "The health effects of processes such as pregnancy and aging."

At [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), what's on topic includes "safety considerations,
food and **feeding**,
**health** and hygiene,
development and growth."

[This](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-do-i-determine-a-target-time-frame-for-breastfeeding) is a question that directly prompted the meta question being raised. 
Where does it fit better?  Are there guidelines or decision rules about what goes where?

There's also [this discussion](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/create-pediatrics-tag-burn-children) about pediatrics & children tags.

Comment: Not going to commit to a full answer at this moment, but I think that question is perfect here.

Comment: It's worth noting [that](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-do-i-determine-a-target-time-frame-for-breastfeeding) is a question I feel fully qualified to answer, and was putting it up to meet the guidelines discussed [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/452/tour-example-questions-copied-from-gardening-landscaping), which are surprisingly difficult to reach for a good question.  Further teasing out differences in regulatory guidelines might be more suited for a biology based background more likely found in Health rather than Parenting.

Comment: @WBT - please remember that on meta, a down vote only means "I disagree", not "This is not a useful question."

Comment: @anongoodnurse Disagree with what? My question here asks a question rather than makes a statement.  I expected answers of the form "here," "at Parenting," or (better) answers with various splits giving reasoning for what goes where, and hoped people would upvote/downvote those *answers* to indicate agreement/disagreement.  (Your comment on Joe W's answer could be an answer of its own!)  Downvotes on the *question* seems to indicate this isn't even a valuable discussion to have.

Comment: "Downvotes on the question seems to indicate this isn't even a valuable discussion to have." This is exactly why I made that comment. Meta voting is different. It's like this on every site I'm on.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I recognize that's why you made the comment, but you say downvotes indicate a disagreement.  Again I ask: disagreement *with what?* My question asks a question.  Unlike expected *answers*, the *question* does not make a statement subject to agreement/disagreement.  The question states some verifiable facts about content of relevant pages, and conveys that this seems like a valuable question to discuss; it seems that only the latter concept is subject to agreement/disagreement.

Answer (score 7):

They can be posted on either site. It should always be remembered that it doesn't matter if a question can or cannot go on another site. All that matters is if the question fits and follows the guidelines of the site that it is posted on.

In the case of the question you posted I think it is a good question for both sites but it might get better answers on parenting.

A site should never turn away content just because it can also be asked elsewhere.

Comment: As a moderator on both sites (Parenting and Health), I can assure you it will get a much better answer here. Parenting has no requirements for supporting sources, so a lot of it is opinion. If it resonates with a lot of people, it will get upvoted whether it is the best advice or not.